# Reverse each word in a sentence using C++ need code optimization for my code snippet

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below sentence

```
"Where are you going"
```

I want each word should get reversed in a sentence like shown below

```
"erehW era uoy gniog"
```

Thanks in advance.

```
       #include "stdafx.h"
            #include "conio.h"
            #include <string.h>
            #include <iostream>
            using namespace std;
```

//reverse function

```
             void reverse(char* sentence)
            {
                int hold, index = 0;
```

//Here we are calling while loop

```
                while (index >= 0)
                {
```

//loop through the sentence until the null terminated

```
                    while ( sentence[index] != ' ')
                    {
                        if(sentence[index] == '\0')
                            break;
                         index++;
                    }            
             hold = index + 1;  
                index--; 

                    /*
    In your original code,
    This while loop(below) will continue to keep decrementing index 
    even below `0`,You wont exit this while loop until you encounter a ` `.
    For the 1st word of the sentence you will never come out of the loop.
    Hence the check, index>=0
    */

                    while (index >= 0 && sentence[index] != ' ')
                    {
                        cout << sentence[index]; 
                        index--;
                    }
                    cout<<" ";
                    index = hold; 
                    if(sentence[hold-1] == '\0')
                    {
                        index = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
//main function

            int main()
            {

                char* sentence = new char[256];
                cin.getline(sentence, 256);
                reverse(sentence);
                delete[] sentence; // Delete the allocated memory
            }
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting, this question is currently close to unreadable.

Comment: @prakash Why do you think you need an optimization?

Comment: i am using so many loops. it kills performance.

Comment: You have bigger issues than optimizing the code right now, for example you have to fix problems like `#include "conio.h"` and not passing the length of the array first. Also changing you code to use the c++ `std::string` would be a much better use of your time than doing micro-optimizations.

Comment: @prakash Way too much code.  See here: http://ideone.com/S6hmd0

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. please help me on this.

Comment: @prakash I did help you.  You tagged the question as `C++11`, assuming you are using the language library available to that version (in reality, the link uses stuff found in C++ 98).  I bet you're shocked that C++ could be that easy, right?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I need to to reverse the strings in a sentence with out using built-in "reverse()" function.

Comment: @prakash So why tag this as `C++11` if you are not using `C++11` features?   What about extracting each word from the string using the `std::istringstream`?  Are you allowed to do that?  How about using `std::string`?  If so, then reverse a single string and just call that function in a loop for each string.  If it's not, then might as well code in `C` since your current code doesn't use anything of `C++` except `new`, `delete`, and `cin / cout`.  Also, if you want "code optimization", more than likely using C++ features will run faster than your hand-coded loops.

Answer (score 0):

For a task like this, the processor is essentially guaranteed to be I/O bound, almost regardless of how slowly you do the reversal itself (and in this case, reading from/writing to main memory counts as I/O).

As such, the primary optimization is to keep the code as simple and readable as possible. With that in mind, I'd start with something like this:

```
std::string reverse_words(std::string const &input) {
    std::istringstream buffer(input);
    std::ostringstream result;

    std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(result, " "),
        [](std::string const &in) { return std::string(in.rbegin(), in.rend()); });
    return result.str();
}
```

If (and only if) profiling the code showed me that this was a bottleneck would I worry about changing this to something else "more efficient".